# Intrinsic parameters fx-fy cx-cy from ARCore Texture API

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working with ARCore I was able to retrieve a resolution image 4032*2268 with Texture API.

How can I retrieve the intrinsic parameters from the image (`fx`,`fy`,`cx`,`cy`)?